# How can I get an Attribute from an Element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, attributes, element

I know this 4 attributes getElementById, getElementsByClassName, getElementsByTagName and getElementsByName
but Facebook has this interesting attribute called ajaxify

```
<a role="button" class="_42ft _4jy0 _4jy3 _517h _51sy" href="#" ajaxify="/ajax/groups/mall/approve/?group_id=29702291481682&amp;message_ids=490372844781280" rel="async-post">
```

Yeah..., I only would like to learn how to get custom attributes

Comment: They are attributes (in this case functions) of a js DOM element and not an attribute of HTML tag.

Comment: `var attribute = element.getAttribute("ajaxify");`

Comment: `getElementById, getElementsByClassName, getElementsByTagName and getElementsByName` are all *methods* not *attributes* and they are all outdated and should no longer be used by the way.

Comment: `let attribute = document.querySelector("[role='button']").getAttribute("ajaxify")`

Comment: Thank you all people  <3

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a specific element based on an attribute you would use [`querySelector()`](https://devdocs.io/dom/document/queryselector) or [`querySelectorAll()`](https://devdocs.io/dom/element/queryselectorall) using an [Attribute Selector](https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/).

```js
const el = document.querySelector('[ajaxify]');
console.log(el.getAttribute('ajaxify'));
```

```html
<div>
  <a role="button" class="_42ft _4jy0 _4jy3 _517h _51sy" href="#" ajaxify="/ajax/groups/mall/approve/?group_id=29702291481682&amp;message_ids=490372844781280" rel="async-post">dasdas</a> - 
  <a href="somewhere.com">somewhere.com</a>
</div>
```

The first line finds the first element that has an attribute named `'ajaxify'`.

The second line gets the value of the `'ajaxify'` attribute on that element.

Answer (score 0):

Just get element by class[n] and then get the attribute ajaxify

```
    var classes = document.getElementsByClassName('_42ft _4jy0 _4jy3 _517h _51sy');
    var class1 = classes[0]; //modify as you want
    class1.getAttribute("ajaxify");
```